# What does it mean when cv::minMaxLoc returns the point (-1, -1) as min and max locations?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Using OpenCV 2.3.1.  I am running cv::minMaxLoc() and it is returning the point (-1, -1) for both the minimum and maximum location, with 0 as the value for both.  What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the relevant sections of code for the [minMaxLoc](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=minmaxloc#void%20minMaxLoc%28InputArray%20src,%20double%2a%20minVal,%20double%2a%20maxVal,%20Point%2a%20minLoc,%20Point%2a%20maxLoc,%20InputArray%20mask%29) function:

```
static void ofs2idx(const Mat& a, size_t ofs, int* idx)
{
    int i, d = a.dims;
    if( ofs > 0 )
    {
        ofs--;
        for( i = d-1; i >= 0; i-- )
        {
            int sz = a.size[i];
            idx[i] = (int)(ofs % sz);
            ofs /= sz;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for( i = d-1; i >= 0; i-- )
            idx[i] = -1;
    }
}

}

void cv::minMaxIdx(InputArray _src, double* minVal,
                   double* maxVal, int* minIdx, int* maxIdx,
                   InputArray _mask)
{
    Mat src = _src.getMat(), mask = _mask.getMat();
    int depth = src.depth(), cn = src.channels();

    CV_Assert( (cn == 1 && (mask.empty() || mask.type() == CV_8U)) ||
               (cn >= 1 && mask.empty() && !minIdx && !maxIdx) );
    MinMaxIdxFunc func = minmaxTab[depth];
    CV_Assert( func != 0 );

    const Mat* arrays[] = {&src, &mask, 0};
    uchar* ptrs[2];
    NAryMatIterator it(arrays, ptrs);

    size_t minidx = 0, maxidx = 0;
    int iminval = INT_MAX, imaxval = INT_MIN;
    float fminval = FLT_MAX, fmaxval = -FLT_MAX;
    double dminval = DBL_MAX, dmaxval = -DBL_MAX;
    size_t startidx = 1;
    int *minval = &iminval, *maxval = &imaxval;
    int planeSize = (int)it.size*cn;

    if( depth == CV_32F )
        minval = (int*)&fminval, maxval = (int*)&fmaxval;
    else if( depth == CV_64F )
        minval = (int*)&dminval, maxval = (int*)&dmaxval;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < it.nplanes; i++, ++it, startidx += planeSize )
        func( ptrs[0], ptrs[1], minval, maxval, &minidx, &maxidx, planeSize, startidx );

    if( minidx == 0 )
        dminval = dmaxval = 0;
    else if( depth == CV_32F )
        dminval = fminval, dmaxval = fmaxval;
    else if( depth <= CV_32S )
        dminval = iminval, dmaxval = imaxval;

    if( minVal )
        *minVal = dminval;
    if( maxVal )
        *maxVal = dmaxval;

    if( minIdx )
        ofs2idx(src, minidx, minIdx);
    if( maxIdx )
        ofs2idx(src, maxidx, maxIdx);
}    

void cv::minMaxLoc( InputArray _img, double* minVal, double* maxVal,
                Point* minLoc, Point* maxLoc, InputArray mask )
{
    Mat img = _img.getMat();
    CV_Assert(img.dims <= 2);

    minMaxIdx(_img, minVal, maxVal, (int*)minLoc, (int*)maxLoc, mask);
    if( minLoc )
        std::swap(minLoc->x, minLoc->y);
    if( maxLoc )
        std::swap(maxLoc->x, maxLoc->y);
}
```

Judging from the code flow it appears you have the case of `minidx` equal to zero, which then sets `dminval = dmaxval = 0`. Also, within the `ofs2idx` function, when `minidx` (i.e.,  `ofs` parameter in `ofs2idx`) is equal to zero the logic sets the min and max points to (-1, -1) (i.e., `idx[i] = -1;`). This might happen if your matrix has no elements. What is the size of the matrix you are trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly cryptic way of minMaxLoc telling you that the concepts of "minimum" and "maximum" do not apply well to your matrix. Let's see what this means. Essentially, minMaxLoc determines the location of the minimum and maximum by going over all values in the matrix. In pseudo-code, the algorithm looks approximately as follows:

```
# initialization
minimum_value = Infinity
maximum_value = -Infinity

minimum_position = Unknown
maximum position = Unknown

for every element in matrix
    # determine if we have a candidate for the minimum
    if element.value < minimum_value
        minimum_value = element.value
        minimum_position = elment.position

    # determine if we have a candidate for the maximum
    if element.value > maximum_value
        maximum_value = element.value
        maximum_position = element.position
```

Now, observe that there are two paths through this code that leave the `minimum_location` set to `Unknown`:

1. the contents of the `for`clause are never executed at all
2. the contents of the first `if` clause are never executed

How can that happen? Well, the first case happens if there are no elements in the matrix (empty matrix). The second happens if for every element in the matrix, the comparison `element.value < minimum_value` is false. This can mean two things: either all elements are `Infinity` or they are all `NaN`. A similar reasoning applies in the case of `maximum_location`.

So, the problem is in your asking for a "minimum" and "maximum" in a context where these two concepts are – at best – ambiguous.